# jQuery, performing a function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a finance calculator with jQuery which is working well. The calculator uses jQuery sliders. I have the following function which is called when a slider is activated.

However I need to replicate this so the same actions are called on page load, could anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#slider-deposit").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: <?php echo json_encode($minDeposit); ?>,
        max: <?php echo json_encode($maxDeposit); ?>,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount-deposit").val(Number(ui.value).toFixed(2));
            totalPayableFunc();
            monthlyPaymentsFunc();
        }
    });
    $("#amount-deposit").val("" + $("#slider-deposit").slider("value"));
});
```

Comment: You are doing right, but what is the issue you are facing? Any error(s) in the console.

Comment: What excatly do you want it to happen on page load?

Comment: just call the function `totalPayableFunc();monthlyPaymentsFunc();` right after `$("#amount-deposit").val("" + $("#slider-deposit").slider("value"));` i.e. last line of above code.

Comment: Essentially I need to call the two functions, totalPayableFunc(); and monthlyPaymentsFunc();

Comment: You need to call the functions on pageload right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#slider-deposit").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: <?php echo json_encode($minDeposit); ?>,
        max: <?php echo json_encode($maxDeposit); ?>,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount-deposit").val(Number(ui.value).toFixed(2));
            totalPayableFunc();
            monthlyPaymentsFunc();
        }
    });
    $("#amount-deposit").val("" + $("#slider-deposit").slider("value"));
    totalPayableFunc();
    monthlyPaymentsFunc();
});
```